# Text search on email domain with postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'd like to have a text search that can also retrieve results matching the domain name in an email address:

Say I have this table of tweets

```
create table tweets (
  id uuid primary key,
  tweet text not null,
)
```

and a seeding like

```
insert into tweets (id,tweet) values
(gen_random_uuid(), 'Hello friends! #example-tweet'),
(gen_random_uuid(), 'Reach me out james@example.com'),
(gen_random_uuid(), 'For example, I want you to finish this'),
(gen_random_uuid(), 'James is a bad guy #james'),
(gen_random_uuid(), 'Hahaha found the email: karl@gmail.com');
```

the following query does **NOT** list the `Reach me out james@example.com` as result

```
SELECT tweet, ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(t.tweet), query) AS rank
FROM tweets t, to_tsquery('example') query
WHERE query @@ to_tsvector(t.tweet)
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Can I make a text search on tweets returning also email domains or internal parts of a string?

Comment: Based on your example, it is not clear what you mean by 'domain'. Usually the domain would be 'example.com', not just 'example'.  Do you mean to take only the first component of the domain, or is there some other rule?  Also, your example has at most one email per value.  Is that the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default parser for FTS will yield emails addresses as a token type, but does not break them down to domains, as can be seen by doing `select * from ts_debug('Reach me out james@example.com');`

So doing what you want would require either writing a custom parser (not easy) or doing some kind of text processing of your own before, after, or instead of FTS processing.  Maybe something like regexp_matches could be used for this, although it is not exactly clear what behavior you want.